# "I am lost too" or "I am too lost"

Tags: word-usage, adverbs, word-order

Which of the following sentences is better?

> 1.​ Don't follow me, I am **too** lost.
>
> 2.​ Don't follow me, I am lost **too**.

Where should I put *too* when it means 'also'?

Comment: 1) I am too lost - **I'm very lost.** 2) I'm lost too - **I'm also lost.**

Comment: You can also say, "I, too, am lost" -- which is more formal than "I'm lost too".  I, too, have misgivings about the stability of this bridge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's all dependant on the position of the word *too*, the second one is correct.

> Don't follow me, I'm lost too.

Here *too* is used to mean *as well* or *also*.

---

> Don't follow me, I'm too lost

Because of the position of *too* the first sentence uses *too* to modify *lost*, but lost is absolute - you either are lost or you are not, there is no scale of 'lostness' even though you might hear people saying "I'm a little bit lost".

You might use "a little bit lost" when you are in a big city and you have taken a ride to an area you are unfamiliar with - you know your are in X City (so you are not lost) but you don't know the immediate area you are currently in (so you are lost).

You could say "Don't follow me, I'm also lost" but when you use *too* before *lost* it doesn't take the meaning of *also*

---

The [definition of *too* at Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/too) provides a number of definitions and some examples. Definitions 1 and 2 are the ones in use in your two sentences.

Comment: I would consider substituting *so* for *too* in the first sentence (I am too lost >  I am so lost).  A lot of English Learners mix up the use of *so* and *too.*

Comment: @CarSmack Indeed, _so_ would work fine there giving a quite modern phrasing.

Answer (score 4):

> Don't follow me, I am too lost.
>
> Don't follow me, I am lost too.

When *too* means *as well* or *also*, it needs to go after any complements of the verb:

- I posted Dave a letter too.
- *I posted Dave too a letter. (wrong)
- I bet him five pounds too.
- *I bet him too five pounds. (wrong)

However, it does not need to go after any adjuncts (adjuncts are extra bits of information, usually about when, where, why or how we did something that we usually put at the end of the sentence):

- I posted Dave a letter too last Friday.
- I bet him five pounds too for fun.

If *too* appears earlier in the sentence it will be interpreted as the degree adverb *too*, which is the word we find in sentences like *too early* or *too much*.

In the Original Poster's second sentence, *too* comes after the adjective *lost*. Here *lost* is the complement of the verb *BE*. So we understand the second sentence to mean:

- Don't follow me, I am lost also.

In the first example, where *too* comes before the complement (before *lost*), we interpret *too* as a degree adverb. The fist sentence means something like:

- Don't follow me, I am very lost. ( - which will be a problem if you follow me)

Hope this helps!